# Transfer Domain purchased from Google Workspace(Enom) to another Domain registrar

Tags: dns, google-workspace

Initially, the domain was purchased while setting up Google Workspace(Enom). We have migrated from Google Workspace to M365. However, having trouble getting the Domain out of Google.